# How open binary file

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems, kali-linux, binary-files

I have a file called `AndroidManifest.xml` I'm studying about injecting the payload manually, and for that I need to open the file to look for another file, only when I open the characters it looks like this:

```
^ A @ ^ B @ ^ H
```

And so on, I ran this command, it shows:

```
charset = binary
```

that is in binary, but how can I open it and read it legibly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file

Comment: In case the file is already decompiled, I am following this tutorial, but the file in the apk I am trying to do is not readable. https://medium.com/@nimishjain511/creating-a-backdoor-in-apks-a4aae59f4e06